# Export-csv creates an empty csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

This is my first PowerShell script and I've went over lots of topics but can't seem to find what is wrong. I'm trying to see if files with two extensions are created in a folder 'today' and output filename and date into a csv file.

My code is:

```
Get-ChildItem 'PATH' -recurse -include @("*.txt*","*.txt.gz") | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).Date } Select-Object FullName, CreationTime, @{Name="Mbytes";Expression={$_.Length/1Kb}}, @{Name="Age";Expression={(((Get-Date) - $_.CreationTime).Days)}} | Export-Csv -path 'PATH' -Append
```

The file gets created, but no data is put into it, even if the info I need is displayed in the PowerShell window when running the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `|`pipeline between the `Where-Object` and the `Select-Object` cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem 'PATH' -recurse -include @("*.txt*","*.txt.gz") | 
    Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).Date } | 
    Select-Object FullName, 
        CreationTime, 
        @{Name="Mbytes";Expression={$_.Length/1Kb}},
        @{Name="Age";Expression={(((Get-Date) - $_.CreationTime).Days)}} | 
    Export-Csv -path 'PATH' -Append
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a missing pipe after .Date }